# Does parent-child defect relationship exist in HP ALM

Tags: quality-center, hp-quality-center, hp-alm

There is a situation when it whould be useful to have parent-child defect relationship:

- Parent defect: 'Print' button only creates blank word document (it should be filled in with data)
- Child defect: 'Print' button creates word document with incorrect data

So when the parent bug is fixed the child is to be checked compulsory.

But when the child bug is fixed there is defenetly no need to check the parent bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure but I don't think there is such a feature. you can only link defects on the same level.

**Note** And you can also link requirements and tests but that has nothing to do with this topic.

Comment: I could not find documentation on HP ALM, but official Tutorial "HP Application Lifecycle Management" v.11.00 says nothing about this. Just relationship on the same level: Defect--Test--Requirement